# $this->getRequest()->getParam() not working in category controller

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am working on retriving the manufacturer attribute from url

**localhost/magento/index.php/test-pro.html?manufacturer/4**

So i used `$this->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturer')`

I did not get any output.

But when i changed the url as **localhost/magento/index.php/test-pro.html?manufacturer=4**
(/ replaced by =), i get proper output.

But i need the url should be **localhost/magento/index.php/test-pro.html?manufacturer/4**

and want to fetch the product related to that manufacturer id 4.

Somebody help me.

Comment: hi use this code <?php echo  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('manufacturer')?>

Comment: I tried that too. But no progress. @RaviChomal

Comment: please disable your site cache after that you will use.

Comment: I disabled cache and refreshed cache already.

Comment: you should replace '?' with '/' if url_rewrite is on

Comment: Ya. I did that too.. but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query string **?manufacturer=4** will give you the value for `manufacturer` i.e. 4, while **manufacturer/4** will give you no value as its not being treated as query string.

Also the param will be and the param will be **manufacturer/4** and not **manufacturer**.

To achieve what you require, you can do sometinhg like below.

```
$currentUrl = 'localhost/magento/index.php/test-pro.html?manufacturer/4';
$parts = parse_url($currentUrl);
$val =  explode('/',$parts['query']);
Mage::register('manufacturer',$val[1]);
$menuVal = Mage::registry('manufacturer');
echo $menuVal; //prints 4
```

This is a sample code by which you can get the query string value even if you use `/` instead of `=`.

Comment: Sorry. But the products related to that manufacturer not retrived.
Is there any way to change the query string format?

Comment: The above code is to retrieve the value of query string `manufacturer ` and not the products related to it.

Comment: Ok. i understood. But how get the products related to that manufacturer?

Comment: Almost a year later, but what the heck :) ...have you tried `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', $menuVal)`?